# Python 3 Can't makes importlib works with py2exe or cxfreeze

Tags: python-3.x, py2exe, python-importlib

My code is working fine when i run it with python but if i try to use py2exe or cxfreeze importlib module isn't working, and i've been looking for a while now to get it working..

heres the part of my code not working (im 99% sure its):

```
idm = cc.GetModule("idmantypeinfo.tlb")
name = str(idm)
module = name[9:65]
IDMan = importlib.import_module(module)
```

this works with python via console, but it instantly crash when compiled after it calls IDMan:

```
idm1 = cc.CreateObject("IDMan.CIDMLinkTransmitter", None, None, IDMan.ICIDMLinkTransmitter2)
```

this is because of that part :

```
module = name[9:65]
IDMan = importlib.import_module(module)
```

which should give me an object but after compiling with py2exe or cxfreeze (even pyinstaller) it just gives me a string because importlib isn't working i've no idea how to fix that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working with cx, i simply forgot to link the build options.. included comtypes & importlib, problem solved.